# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no customer

Tags: django, django-views

I am following a Django youtube E-comerce tutorial by Dennis Ivy. I follow the tutorial line by line. from the initial i use to run the program and view all the output but alone the way i start getting this error message "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no customer". Am confuse because i keep repeating the video to see where i was wrong but could not trace it. please what is the solution? I realise the last time i tried, it open on its own using 'internet explorer' it display. when i open in 'chrome', it show the same erro. but when i deleted a customer from database it start showing the same erro again in 'internet explorer'. I dont want to give up on the tutorial cos i need it. please someone should assist me. Thanks

```
from multiprocessing import context
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

# Create your views here.
def store(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete =False)
        items =order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems=order.get_cart_items

    else:
        items=[]
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
        cartItems=order['get_cart_items']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        'products':products,
        'cartItems':cartItems,
        
        
    }
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete =False)
        items =order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems=order.get_cart_items
        
    else:
        items=[]
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
        cartItems=order['get_cart_items']
    
    context = {
        'items':items,
        'order':order,
        'cartItems':cartItems,
    }
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def checkout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete =False)
       # order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(complete =False)
        items =order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items=[]
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
        cartItems=order['get_cart_items']
    
    context = {
        'items':items,
        'order':order,
        'cartItems':cartItems
    }
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)

def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']

    print('Action:', action)
    print('productId:', productId)

    customer=request.user.customer
    product=Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(complete =False)

    orderItem, created=OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action =='add':
        orderItem.quantity =(orderItem.quantity +1)
    elif action =='remove':
        orderItem.quantity =(orderItem.quantity -1)
        orderItem.save()
    
    if orderItem.quantity <=0:
        orderItem.delete()



    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe =False)
```

this is the models.py

```
import email
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields.related import OneToOneField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from numpy import product 

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

        

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital=models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    #this is  to avoid erro in the template when we delete image
    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url=self.image.url
        except:
            url=''
        return url


class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total

    


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total


class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    address= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

this is the urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.store, name = 'store'),
    path('cart/', views.cart, name = 'cart'),
    path('checkout', views.checkout, name = 'checkout'),
    path('update_item/', views.updateItem, name='update_item')
]
```

Comment: You did not construct a `Customer` object for the user with which you logged in...

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Ways to solve it

You can either add the code below inside step 1 or 2 which you need to run in the shell(inside your app folder)

1. Create in your app folder this file , create_customers.py
2. Open the app folder in terminal and run the command below

   python manage.py shell

   then paste the code below into shell

   from django.contrib.auth.models import User

   from store.models import Customer

   for user in User.objects.all():
   Customer.objects.create(user=user, name=user.username, email=user.email)

Answer (score -1):

you can use the request.user to query the customer

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(user__id = request.user.id)
```

Comment: I tried but up to now